# Getting a specific number from a bigger number?

Tags: lua

a = (any random number)
Is there a way could I get the third number (12**3**45) without converting it into a string?
If not, what would be a good way to get it by converting it into a string?

Comment: `b = string.sub(a,3,3)+0`

Comment: `b = a//100%10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sub function

```
function getDigit(value,digitPlace) 
return tonumber(tostring(value):sub(digitPlace,digitPlace))
end
```

This will get the third digit of a as a number:

```
a = 12345
print(getDigit(a,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that using simple maths.

```
function getDigitInt(value, digit)
  -- get rid of the sign
  value = math.abs(value)
  -- how many digits does the number have?
  local numDigits = math.floor(math.log(value, 10)) + 1
  -- does the requested digit exist?
  if digit > numDigits or digit < 1 then
    print("digit does not exist")
    return
  end
  -- return the requested digit
  return math.floor(value / 10^(numDigits - digit)) % 10
end
-- test
for i = 0, 8 do print(getDigitInt(1234567, i)) end
```

Add more error handling as needed. Also this can only handle integers of course. But I'm sure you will find out how to apply this idea to decimals as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the number into array and find the any place easily like blow

```html
public int GetDigitsPlace(int number, int digitPlace) {
    string t = number.ToString();
    int[] nArr = new int[t.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < nArr.Length; i++) {
        nArr[i] = int.Parse(t[i]);
    }
    return nArr[digitPlace];
}
```

Comment: the question is tagged with `lua` and it explicitly asks how to do it without converting the number to a string. I'm not sure how your Java? answer helps here. Assuming this is Java, why not simply use charAt? why run a loop to fill an array instead?